# PHP chdir() and redirect() causes 500 internal server error on IIS

Tags: php, redirect, iis, chdir

I made a function for user to create a video from images (using mencoder). Unfortunately, I was not able to set path to image list directly in command (I searched for solutions but it looks impossible in windows), so I had to change working directory in php script. After command execution I change the dir back to previous and then redirect to other page. It looks like this combination of orders causes 500 Internal server error on IIS (it works properly on Apache)

```
chdir($path_images);

exec($mencoder." mf://*.png -mf w=1920:h=1080:fps=25:type=png -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=4000 -o output.avi");

chdir($path_to_default_working_directory);

redirect('home');
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

UPDATE:
Here is a screenshot from detail error message.
[image]

Comment: what do your logs show?

Comment: I'm IIS beginner and can't find any log file (excepts of some ftp logs, u_extend.log)

Comment: Use error reporting then http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and set to catch and display, see if anything comes of it.

Comment: A 500 error means one thing and one thing only: Read the error log! As a 500 error can be caused by dozens of reasons, there's not a singular answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

First, enable user friendly errors in IIS, so you can get exact error message rather generic 500.

1. Login to IIS Manager.
2. Expand the sites and select your website name.
3. From the Feature view, Under ASP.Net section select ASP.Net.
4. Under debug, click on "send error to browsers" option and set it True.
5. Save the settings.

Also,

1. From the Feature view, Under IIS section select Error message.
2. Select the 500 error and right click on it.
3. Select the "Edit Feature Settings".
4. Select "Detailed Error" and click OK to save the settings.